# Easyest way to setup encrypted volume

Tags: linux, partition, encryption, privacy

What is the easyest way to set encrypted volume under linux?

Basically, what I want is to have fixed size file in my home folder. When I mount it and type password, it should appear as regular folder. I should also be able to umount it.

If it would be possible to prevend other users, including root, to access it while mounted, it would be a bonus.

It shouldn't depend on any kernel featueres or configuration, cause I want to be able to mount it later on another computer.

Comment: This question needs a better title.  It has nothing to do with partitions, and it does not say it is about encryption for *one user* only.  I'm inclined to move this one to superuser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your last requirement screams 'Truecrypt'. There are some other options (like EncFS and luks / cryptsetup), but I wouldn't exactly call those 'easy' if you do not set them up during installation. A Truecrypt volume is most likely not a partition, it would be a file, but from your question, I guess that would be ok.

If mounted, root would be able to read it though, and I doubt a solution exists where root would be banned from reading the mounted partition / file. After all, root is God. I suppose you would be able to mimic what you want on a system with SELinux in strict mode, but building such a system is opening up a huge can of worms by itself.

So: [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Comment: Got to agree - truecrypt ticks all the boxes - and if you are using a file as a virtual partition ... it can be copied and mounted on other machines as well. I've used Truecrypt volume files to copy files between Linux and Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to TrueCrypt, here a nice article from Linux Journal : [Protecting Files at Home Using Encrypted Containers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8599).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not called an encrypted "partition".  What you probably meant was "volume".  For encrypted **actual partitions**, LUKS /cryptsetup is by far the more sensible tool.

Answer (score 0):

I second the above answer, Trucrypt is  definitely your tool of choice.